# Access a variable based on other variable value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a bunch of variables having boolean values. I wish to have another variable that stores the name of the boolean variable changed last. So, next time when a new boolean variable value is changed, I want to toggle the previous boolean variable.

Any idea/suggestion to achieve the above would be highly appreciated.

Eg. it would be something like this incorrect code-

```
isDemo1=false; isDemo2=false; isDemo3=true; isDemo4=false; isDemo5=false; 

lastChangedBooleanVariable = this.isDemo3;

handleBooleanVaiables(currentChangedBooleanVariable: string)
{
// somehow toggle this.isDemo3 variable value
this.lastChangedBooleanVariable = currentChangedBooleanVariable;
// let's say currentChangedBooleanVariable = isDemo4
// somehow toggle this.isDemo4 value
}
```

Comment: An [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays) and a variable for the index will help you here.

Comment: Do you just want to keep track which of the Boolean variables were changed last? Is it possible for more than 1 to change at the same time? And is the number of Boolean variables always 5?

Comment: @KnightIndustries  That was my first thought, but I don't want to manually enter multiple variables into an array. Also, these boolean variables are bound to HTML part of the component.

Comment: @FaitAccompli No, only one variable at a time. No, total number can be more than 5.

Comment: I believe the questioner also wants to know how to get the variable name and how to toggle the variable, not merely how to reference an object property by name.

Answer (score 1):

Everytime that you need to do some weird code, rethink your approach, it will probably wrong.

You can instead use [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array):

```
isDemo = [false, false, true, false, false];

lastChangedBooleanVariable = 3;


handleBooleanVaiables(currentChangedBooleanVariable: int) {
  this.lastChangedBooleanVariable = currentChangedBooleanVariable;
  isDemo[currentChangedBooleanVariable - 1] = !isDemo[currentChangedBooleanVariable - 1]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds very much like what you're trying to do is functionally equivalent to:

```
let demo = 3;
```

Then set the value of this variable to any value from `1` to `5`.
Instead of `if (isDemo2)`, test `if (demo == 2)`.
The "last changed variable" is always simply the current value `demo` holds, and that's probably obsolete information with this approach.

Comment: Since you mentioned that it can be more than 5 Boolean variables bound to HTML components and one can be changed at a time then this is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

ES6 has a feature on [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) called `fill` which can be pretty handy here. Essentially, you just set all the values to `false` before you activate a new version.

```
let demos = new Array(5).fill(false);

function activateDemo(demo) {
  demos = new Array(5).fill(false);
  demos[demo] = true;
}

activateDemo(4);
```

```js
let demos = new Array(5).fill(false);

function activateDemo(demo) {
  const humanIndex = demo > 0 ? demo - 1 : 0; // to make it into human counting form, if you want.
  demos = new Array(5).fill(false);
  demos[humanIndex] = true;

}


activateDemo(4);
console.log("4", demos);
activateDemo(3);
console.log("3", demos);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var keys = {
"isDemo1":false, "isDemo2":false, "isDemo3":false, "isDemo4":false, "isDemo5":false;
};
var lastChangedBooleanVariable: string = "isDemo3";
const nameOf = (f) => (f).toString().replace(/[ |\(\)=>]/g,'');
function getName(varName:string){
    return varName.substring(
        varName.indexOf(".") + 1, 
        varName.lastIndexOf(";")
    );
}
function handleBooleanVaiables(currentChangedBooleanVariable: string)
{
    console.log(keys[lastChangedBooleanVariable]);
    keys[lastChangedBooleanVariable] = !keys[lastChangedBooleanVariable];
    keys[currentChangedBooleanVariable] = ! keys[currentChangedBooleanVariable];

    lastChangedBooleanVariable = currentChangedBooleanVariable;
    // let's say currentChangedBooleanVariable = isDemo4
    // somehow toggle this.isDemo4 value
}
function printValues(){
    console.log(keys);
}


var varName = getName(nameOf(()=>keys.isDemo1));
handleBooleanVaiables(varName);
printValues();

varName = getName(nameOf(()=>keys.isDemo4));
handleBooleanVaiables(varName);
printValues();
```

here's fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hjv540tk/